# Credential Authentication is Failing to execute using NextAuth in NextJs App router

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth, next.js13

I'm trying to use a custom login page in `NextJs` along with `NextAuth`. When I try to sign in there is no logging happening inside the `NextAuth` authorize function. In the frontend, there is no error even if I return `null` or throw an error inside the authorize function i.e. declared while defining `NextAuthOptions`.

**/utils/auth.ts**

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    pages: {
        signIn: "/login"
    },
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt"
    },
    providers : [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!
        }),
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "Sign In",
            credentials: {
                username: { label: "Username", type: "text"},
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password"}
            }, 
            async authorize(credentials) {
                console.log("Credentials: ", credentials)
                if (!credentials?.username || !credentials.password) {
                    throw new Error("Invalid credentials")
                }
                let userFromDb = await authenticateUser(credentials?.username!, credentials?.password!)
                let returnUser = userFromDb ? {
                    id : userFromDb.id,
                    username: userFromDb.username,
                    bio: userFromDb.bio,
                    name: userFromDb.name,
                    profilePic: userFromDb.profilePic
                } : null

                return returnUser
            },
        })
    ],
}
```

**/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts**

```
const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)
export {handler as GET, handler as POST}
```

**/app/login**

```
  const submitData:SubmitHandler<FormSchema> = async (data: FormSchema) => {
    
    console.log("Input data:", data)
    
    const res = await signIn("credentials", {
      redirect: false,
      callbackUrl:"/",
      ...data,
    })
    console.log("response: ", res)
    if (!res?.error) {
      router.push("/")
    } else {
      console.log("Errors: ", res.error)
    }
  };
```

**reponse on frontend:**

```
response {
error: null
ok: true
status: 200
url: "https://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?csrf=true"
}
```

This response is even when you throw an error or return null inside the authorize.

I feel like the control is never reaching the authorize, as there's no logging happening inside it.

I've tried debugging the code and also looked at various people's code. Can't seem to understand the reason for this bug.